# How to stub a variable defined on html before test run

Tags: cypress

In my index.html, i'm creating an instance of my Widget. I wanna be able to stub the `options` before test runs to try different initializations.

```js
<html>
<body>
  ...
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var options = {
        input_element_id: 'inputid',
        list: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        app_id: 'xxx'
        api_key: 'xxx'
      }
      var widget = new MyWidget(options)

      widget.start()
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i do this with Cypress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach that i found was expose the variables to cypress using the window object. Then, in the test i can manipulate those.

```html
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var options = {...}
      var widget = new MyWidget(options)

      if (window.Cypress) {
        window.options = options
        window.widget = widget
      }

      widget.start()
    })
</script>
```

Then in my test i can run this on `beforeEach()` or where I need it

```js
  cy.window()
    .then(win => {
      win.options['search_on_slash'] = false
    })
```